# Angular, File not uploaded to Firebase Storage

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I'm trying to make an upload function for uploading file/image to my firebase database storage. I have already paste the correct API key in the `environment.ts` and import it to `app.module.ts` like `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfiguration, 'app-root')`. I made the push string properties function and upload file function separately. The other properties like name and description are pushed correctly into my Firebase real-time database but the file is not uploaded to the storage so i also cant obtain the url.

```js
//product.ts
export class Product {
  $prdKey: string;
  prdName: string;
  prdImage ? : File;
  imageURL ? : any;
  prdDescription: string;

  constructor(prdImage: File) {
    this.prdImage = prdImage;
  }
}
```

```js
//product.service.ts
Product: any;
selectedProduct: Product = new Product(this.Product);
currentFileUpload: Product;

insertProduct(Product: Product) {
  this.productList.push({
    prdName: Product.prdName,
    prdDescription: Product.prdDescription
  });
}

private basePath = '/';
pushFileToStorage(Product: Product) {
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${Product.prdImage.name}`).put(Product.prdImage);

  uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    (snapshot) => {
      // in progress
      const snap = snapshot as firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot
    },
    (error) => {
      // fail
      console.log(error)
    },
    () => {
      // success
      Product.imageURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
      Product.prdName = Product.prdImage.name
      this.saveFileData(Product)
    }
  );
}

private saveFileData(Product: Product) {
  this.firebase.list(`${this.basePath}/`).push(Product);
}
```

```js
//product.component.ts

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  if (form.value.$prdKey == null) {
    this.ProductService.insertProduct(this.ProductService.selectedProduct);
  } else {
    this.ProductService.updateProduct(this.ProductService.selectedProduct);
  }

}

upload() {
  const file = this.ProductService.selectedProduct.prdImage
  this.ProductService.currentFileUpload = new Product(file);
}

selectFile(event) {
  this.ProductService.selectedProduct = event.target.files;
}
```

```html
<!--product.component.html-->
<form #productForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(productForm); upload()">
  <!--skip name and descrioption input-->
  <label>Upload an Image</label>
  <input type="file" class="form-control">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me solve this? Please let me know of more snippets are needed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ends up and are using angular/fire6 then the following should work if you wish to upload an image to storage.

```
onFileChange(event: any) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
    // should be a unique filepath 
    const filePath = `blogs/${this.blogId}/${this.file.name}`;

    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, this.file, {
      cacheControl: "max-age=31536000,public"
    })
    // display the image preview to the user  
    task.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        last(),
        concatMap(() => this.storage.ref(filePath).getDownloadURL()),
        tap(blogUrl => this.blogImageUrl = blogUrl),
        catchError(error => {
          alert("Could not create thumbnailUrl");
          return throwError(error)
        })
      ).subscribe();
  }
```